# Why wont my math game made in python open?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm having a problem with my python code, I'm new to python, so yeah. Why isn't it working?

I don't understand what is the problem, it looks like it should be perfectly fine to me. I didn't see anything that helped me either when I looked it up.

```py
from time import sleep
from random import randint
print 'Welcome to the math game!\n\nWhat is your name?'
name = input()
print('Hello, ' + name + '!\n')
n1 = random.randint(1, 100000)
n2 = random.randint(2, 200000)
print('What is ' + n1 + ' * ' + n2 + '?')
answer = input()
if answer == n1 * n2:
    print 'Good job ' + name + ', you are not dumb!'
    sleep(3)
else:
    print(name + ', you are lacking of braincells!')
    sleep(3)
```

I expected it to start and actually work, and then it just closes when I open it.

Comment: what do you mean by "open it"? Are you trying to run it from the command line, or are you double clicking it from some UI?
Also, if you are actually using python 3, your third line would throw an error. `print` statements needs parentheses

Comment: The immediate problem is you're trying to add strings to numbers (in your `print`), which doesn't work in Python, so you get an error. The more important thing is that you need to run the program in a way where you can see its output - I'm guessing you are double-clicking on the file from Windows (or the equivalent in a different OS), so that a black window pops up and closes immediately when the program finishes, which is too fast to see the output or an error message. You will need to learn how to run a program from the command-line before you're able to do much else with Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked, I changed the str+int problem and fixed the print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use a function of random with the `.` operator, just import random. Otherwise you can import the function and call it directly.

Either:

```
import random
n1 = random.randint(1, 100000)
```

or

```
from random import randint
n1 = randint(1, 100000)
```

also, you cannot concatenate ints and strings. You can convert between them though. Try:

`print('What is ' + str(n1) + ' * ' + str(n2) + '?')`

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
import random
print('Welcome to the math game!\n\nWhat is your name?')
name = input()
print('Hello, ' + name + '!\n')
n1 = random.randint(1, 100000)
n2 = random.randint(2, 200000)
print('What is ' + str(n1) + ' * ' + str(n2) + '?')
answer = input()
if answer == n1 * n2:
    print('Good job ' + name + ', you are not dumb!')
    sleep(3)
else:
    print(name + ', you are lacking of braincells!')
    sleep(3)
```

Firstly, as stakSmashr said, your `print()` statements were malformed. Python 3 defines `print` as a function, so it needs the parentheses. Next, your calls to `random.randint()`  are bad. You pull in *only* `randint()` and then try to call it from its module. Either do `n1 = randint(1,100000)` or do what I did and `import` the entire module `random`. Finally, on line 8 you're trying to add an int to a string. You should convert it into a `str` and then concatenate them.